# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MessageMethods.send_message' was never awaited

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

```
import random
from telethon import TelegramClient, events


def main():
    api_id = 9123640
    api_hash = '8as6fgvs8t9ar76fse89rgearz'
    chat = '@username'
    message = 'hi'

    client = TelegramClient('afewfe', api_id, api_hash)

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chat))
    async def normal_handler(event):
        if event.message.button_count == 4:
            await event.message.click(random.randint(0, 3))
            await client.disconnect()

    client.start()
    client.send_message(chat, message)
    client.run_until_disconnected()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to send message to user then get back from user message with 4 buttons, click random button and stop script. Problem with sending message. If I comment line `client.send_message(chat, message)` and send message by myself, code will continue working fine but but line `client.send_message(chat, message)` an error appears:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MessageMethods.send_message' was never awaited
  client.send_message('@username', 'hi')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running asynchronous code in a normal function. The error is complaining that the `client.send_message(chat, message)` code doesn't have the `await` keyword before it. In order to be able to run any async function the way you want to (as just a normal function call), you must have the `await` keyword before the function call's code. To be able to use the await keyword without throwing an error, the outer function holding the code (`main`) needs to be asynchronous and can be run with `asyncio.run`.

```py
from asyncio import run

async def main():
    # your code

    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()
    await client.send_message(chat, message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

Comment: Another error appears: `ConnectionError: Cannot send requests while disconnected`

Comment: In answer to my question I wrote code which I have now

Comment: Try that update, I think it wants the client to be ran and then a message sent. (I switched the last two lines)

Comment: Note that both `start` and `run_until_disconnected` *also* need `await`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from asyncio import run


async def main():
    api_id = 9123640
    api_hash = '8as6fgvs8t9ar76fse89rgearz'
    chat = '@username'
    message = 'hi'

    client = TelegramClient('afewfe', api_id, api_hash)

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chat))
    async def normal_handler(event):
        if event.message.button_count == 4:
            await event.message.click(random.randint(0, 3))
            await client.disconnect()

    client.start()
    await client.send_message(chat, message)
    client.run_until_disconnected()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

Full error:

```
C:\Users\aesok\Desktop\airdroper2\telegram_hi.py:20: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AuthMethods._start' was never awaited
  client.start()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aesok\Desktop\airdroper2\telegram_hi.py", line 25, in <module>
    run(main())
  File "C:\Users\aesok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\aesok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\aesok\Desktop\airdroper2\telegram_hi.py", line 21, in main
    await client.send_message(chat, message)
  File "C:\Users\aesok\Desktop\airdroper2\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\messages.py", line 853, in send_message
    result = await self(request)
  File "C:\Users\aesok\Desktop\airdroper2\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "C:\Users\aesok\Desktop\airdroper2\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 58, in _call
    future = sender.send(request, ordered=ordered)
  File "C:\Users\aesok\Desktop\airdroper2\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 172, in send
    raise ConnectionError('Cannot send requests while disconnected')
ConnectionError: Cannot send requests while disconnected

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please edit your question instead of posting an answer with more details about the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just import:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
```

That should work.